# Function returning an address of the greatest element in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

Somehow this code doesn't work, I get trash numbers as results. Can you guys have a look at it?

```
float * greatest(float *elements,int length){

float max=elements[0];int index=0;

for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
{
    if(max<elements[length]){
        max = elements[length];
        index = length;}
}
return &elements[index];
}
```

Comment: You're using `length` where you want `i` inside your loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(max<elements[length]){
```

Will always return the last element, because the length never changes. You want

```
if(max<elements[i]){
```

Comment: I'm so stupid ,i can't believe i didn't saw this sooner ..Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the indexing bug (`elements[length]` instead of `elements[i]`), C++ already [has that built in](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), no need to reinvent the wheel:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
float * greatest(float *elements,int length){
    return max_element(elements, elements+length);
}
```

Comment: I know it does, but we use this stuff to practice pointers at my college

Comment: @SandroLivaja In that case you might be interested in the fact that `&elements[index] = elements + index`. By the way you didn't ask what's wrong with your code. I had a look at it and figured it's not a particular good way to do it, so I suggested a better way ;)

Comment: Our professor doesn't allow us to use built- in functions . He wants us to think and find our own solution. He thinks we will improve better that way. That fact is interesting, I'll share it in class . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is:

```
float * greatest(float *elements,int length){

float max=elements[0];int index=0;

for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
{
    if(max<elements[i]){
        max = elements[i];
        index = i;}
}
return &elements[index];
}
```